# Why is “to be carrying” used here?

Tags: grammar

They said she was a great girl to be carrying coats upstairs at her age.

Why “to be carrying” is used in the sentence?

What it the difference between “…girl carrying” and “…girl to be carrying”?

When should I use this “to be doing” structure?  Thank you very much[image]

Comment: Good question. I don't see a difference between "_carrying_" and "_to be carrying_" in this context (except perhaps that in the _to be carrying_ version, the guests may be inferrring that the girl always does this). The "_to be_" + present participle construction is common following an adjective, such as in "_He's too young to be playing outside alone_". I'm looking forward to a substantive analysis from one of the site's experts.

Comment: It's just not great.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence you ask about,

> They said she was a great girl to be carrying coats upstairs at her age,

is not entirely idiomatic, at least not in American English. But its only problem is unclarity about what is meant by *great*. Perhaps wonderful, very good, highly praiseworthy, or the like.

As for the fragment *girl to be carrying*, that’s perfectly natural in a sentence like

> She’s a very small girl to be carrying such a heavy suitcase.

Here the progressive *to be carrying* indicates that her carrying is happening at the moment the sentence is spoken. The meaning of the sentence is that her carrying the suitcase is remarkable given its weight and her size.

The sentence

> She’s a very small girl carrying such a heavy suitcase

would be a bit odd. Its beginning seems to suggest that the sentence is performing some kind of identification, like an answer to the question *Who is Janey?* But that kind of use would call for a predicate comprising fairly stable attributes (like being a small girl) and would generally not license attributes as fleeting as being in the act of carrying a suitcase.

Comment: I bet that if it read *a good gird* instead of *a great girl*, nobody would question it. Or even *a big girl* for that matter, given she’s only four years old.